# How do I convert my .project, category/pom/site.xml files into a AngularJS plugin that can be used in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, angularjs, maven

I want to get started with AngularJS but I am running into problems getting the plugin to work in Eclipse.  I downloaded this plugin from Github:  https://github.com/sbegaudeau/AngularJS-Eclipse-Tools

When I follow the instructions in the ReadMe, I wind up with this (I also run mvn --version to make sure it is working):[image]

And now I have a folder that looks like this: 
[image]

How do I convert this Update Site into plugins that can be used in Eclipse?  I looked at the file structure of the plugins already in Eclipse, and they contain Executable Jar Files.  I think I should be able to do some sort of Build/Make (some command) on the files I have to get these executables.

Comment: I decided to just not use the plugin afterall